# How to implement One Tap Login in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento2, google-one-tap

I'm trying to implement Google One Tap Login on our Magento 2 site and I have followed the below guide but not sure where can I start

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web

[image]

Please help me to implement the One Tap Login on my website.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Please follow this link this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311679/how-can-i-login-my-website-with-google-account